# Is it safe to expose AWS Amplify like this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

In my react native app I use Amplify Datastore to query,create and update items. I want to know is it safe to expose these methods in my frontend ? and can someone reverse engineer and use these ? and what can I do to increase the security of these methods ?

```
const getOrder = async () => {
 await DataStore.query(Order, c=>c.iD.eq(currentOrderId)
}

const createOrder = async () => {
 await Datastore.save(new Order({
// }))
}
```

etc

Comment: Where are you storing the keys (i.e. tokens, etc..) for Amplify?

Comment: @VinXi Actually I don't know where find the API key in the front-end, but I can see it at the AWS console.